# Sass/Scss exclude a selector (:root) from nesting when nesting @import

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors, css-root

I am styling an embeded content using styles for the not-embeded view.

Following works out of the box:

```
.embeded-selector {
    @import "library/somelibrary";

    @import "_some_other_styles";
}
```

This puts the `.embeded-selector` before EVERY selector in the imported `somelibrary` to the final CSS, however I've stumbled on one issue - the library defines somewhere inside variables on the root level using the `:root` selector, now obviously I could just search&replace the final CSS and replace all `.embeded-selector :root` with just `:root` and that works...but...

**...is there a way how to exclude the `:root`, or really, any selector from this auto-nesting on the SASS/SCSS level?**

PS: I also looked into the `@at-root` and it doesn't seem it supports a selector in the `without:` . Also picking piece by piece from the library is not really an option.

Comment: Is `:root .selector` valid CSS? But... would `#{unquote(":root")}` maybe work if it is valid?

Comment: @somethinghere the issue is that the result is `.embeded-selector :root` and I can't really go into the library and wrap every `:root` beforehand. So unless there's a special search&replace that could be done on the sass before and after, probably not an option, sorry.

Comment: Even when you use the unquote interpolation? I would have bet that works but I don’t have a quick and easy way to test atm.

Comment: @somethinghere but what do you suggest? Wrapping the ":root" in that interpolation? That would mean modifying the guts of library which is not possible in this case as I've desribed. Or do you suggest somehow wrapping the import with this?